# 504 Gateway Time-out Error on PHP Mail / EC2

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an email using php's mail() function.

It worked fine in my local environment(macos). 
In EC2(ubuntu 16.0.6 LTS), mail is sent but a 504 error occurs.

```
504 Gateway Time-out
nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
```

I checked these things:

- `php.ini` : smtp_port 25
- open SMTP port 25 (inbound, outbound on VPC and sequrity group)

And my php code:

```
<?php

$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "sample@example.com";
$charset = 'UTF-8';

$subject="subject example";

$message = "
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><b>message</b></p>
        <p>$message</p>
    </body>
</html>
";

// headers
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <'sample@example.com'>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I put this php in the action of the form tag.

Has anyone ever experienced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase maximum execution time in php.

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

Comment: Unfortunately, no matter how I change the time, I get a 504 error.